# Are there any alternative methods for calculating the loading time of a web page on the Android?

Tags: android

I know the webview class has onpagestarted() and onpagefinished() methods, which can be used for calculating the load time for a page. Are there any other methods for doing this?
I'm using an Intent object to launch a browser, I'm looking for a method that works under this setup:

```
Uri Url = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
Intent Browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Url );
startActivity(Browser);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the approach of writing your custom code in `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()` is the way. till now, I haven't come across any method which works under the setup where you use Device Browser, since it is loaded separately.